# Delete an item from UICollectionView by tapping on Popup view button

Tags: ios

I am working on a iOS social app.I have a collection view showing some profile images.Images comes from an array I have created earlier.In my app when someone clicks on an collection view cell it shows a pop up view.That popup view contains one UIImageView showing user Profile picture,one like button and a dislike button.I have created -(void)dislikeBtnAction{} for the dislike button.This is the code for 
dislike button.

```
dislikeBtn= [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(159,251,107,34)];
    [dislikeBtn setTitle:@"dislike" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [dislikeBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:138.0/255.0 green:7.0/255.0 blue:7.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [dislikeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(dislikeBtnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    [secondMyView addSubview:dislikeBtn];
```

Now I want when someone clicks on that dislike button the profile image should remove from collection view as well as from the array too.
How to do that? Plz can anyone help me? 
This is the code for dislikeBtnAction.

```
-(void)dislikeBtnAction
     {    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
        [profileImages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` has a method named `-deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:`, you can use it with some `indexPath` and delete item from model that populates that `UICollectionView`

`NSMutableArray` has a `-removeObject:` method

Comment: I used these but every time I run my code it gives me threads

Comment: the thread is :2015-05-18 12:18:44.832 designS[2889:52037] -[UITouchesEvent row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0b9c23730
2015-05-18 12:18:44.884 designS[2889:52037] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITouchesEvent row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0b9c23730'

Comment: Please update your question with that code which crashes and highlight the place of error